# EJS Failed to lookup file in view dictionary

Tags: node.js, ejs

My EJS file is not showing when I use the render function and instead it is showing an error:Error: Failed to lookup view "home.ejs" in views directory

My code:

```
const express = require('express');
const res = require('express/lib/response');
const app = express()
const serveStatic = require('serve-static')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/',(req, res) => {
    res.render('home.ejs')
})
app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('Listening on port 3000')
})
```

I have the latest versions of ejs and express installed, I tried downgrading too but it didn't work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .ejs extension and ensure the **views** folder has the home.ejs

```
const express = require('express');
const res = require('express/lib/response');
const app = express()
const serveStatic = require('serve-static')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/',(req, res) => {
    res.render('home')
})
app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('Listening on port 3000')
})
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work

Comment: can you share the package.json in question

Comment: `{
  "name": "firstapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "i": "^0.3.7"
  },
  
}
`

Comment: from the package lock.json:`"node_modules/ejs": {
      "version": "3.1.8",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ejs/-/ejs-3.1.8.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-/sXZeMlhS0ArkfX2Aw780gJzXSMPnKjtspYZv+f3NiKLlubezAHDU5+9xz6gd3/NhG3txQCo6xlglmTS+oTGEQ==",
      "dependencies": {
        "jake": "^10.8.5"
      },`

Comment: can you put it in the question, by editing the question

Comment: I figured it out, it was looking in a views dictionary, which didn't exist, so I created one and put the file in there.

Comment: I mentioned that in answer. Please feel free to accept the answer.